# View Django User table from MySQL console

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to view `Django default User` table from MySQL console.

I know to access from django shell or python by simply importing it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

is there a way to view it from MySQL console itself?

and where it will be located? i mean in which database django user table belongs?

Comment: It belongs to a database that you connected your app to in ``settings.py``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can see it in the database.

As with all other models, unless instructed otherwise by using a `db_table` property in the Meta class, Django uses the naming schema `appname_modelname` for tables - so in this case the table is `auth_user`.

If you don't know and can't find the source, you can ask the model itself - ie `User._meta.db_table`.

Comment: auth_user ... yes it is .. i forgot. because in my db i am already have auth_user so confused with that. but my auth_user is abstracted from django.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tables are located in the database which you have specified in `settings.py`. The django user table will be located at `yourdbname.auth_user`. All user defined models will be stored as `yourdbname.appname_modelname`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "python manage.py dbshell" (in order to do this in linux, you need to install mysqlclient) and use "show tables;" and "select * from yourdb.table"